# Passed param from form submit is not saved to the database even though it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to Rails and I am trying to save a link to a database but when I submit the link only the time stamps are saved. If I try to use `require` in my controller it says it is empty which confuses me even more.
Is this related to convention I am breaking which Rails does no like ?

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for WatchedLink.new, url: {action: "create"}, html: {class: "links_to_be_scraped"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field (:link) %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

page_to_be_scraped_controller.rb

```
class LinksToBeScrapedController < ApplicationController

  def index     
    @watched_links = WatchedLink.all
  end

  def show
    @watched_links = WatchedLink.find(params[:id])

  end

  def new
    @watched_links = WatchedLink.new


  end

  def create

    @link = WatchedLink.new(params.permit(:watched_link))

    if @link.save 
      puts "ADDED TO THE DATABASE #{params[:watched_link]}"
    else
      puts "FAILED TO ADD TO THE DATABASE"
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def upadate

  end

  def delete

  end

  def destroy

  end
end
```

Log

```
Started POST "/links_to_be_scraped" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-11 03:19:04 +0000
Processing by LinksToBeScrapedController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jMv4C+k0OSkgDAj/Rw6UcZX9hFZHhbG6P4Dcb/2oyeybnVRtuOqscQZEON0rjG0Q/s6Bp6zBlUQIsVEnL5ikiw==", "watched_link"=>{"link"=>"www.google.com"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, watched_link, commit
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `watched_links` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2018-02-11 03:19:04', '2018-02-11 03:19:04')
   (66.5ms)  COMMIT
ADDED TO THE DATABASE {"link"=>"www.google.com"}
No template found for LinksToBeScrapedController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 108ms (ActiveRecord: 66.7ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-11 03:19:06 +0000
Processing by LinksToBeScrapedController#index as HTML
  Rendering links_to_be_scraped/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  WatchedLink Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `watched_links`.* FROM `watched_links`
  Rendered links_to_be_scraped/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 20.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the form with the params `{ watched_link: { link: ... } }`, but in your controller your `create` isn't accessing to watched_link.

Update name of the text_field tag helper in your form:

```
<%= form_for WatchedLink.new, url: { action: "create" }, html: { class: "links_to_be_scraped" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :link %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And in your controller:

```
@link = WatchedLink.new(params.require(:watched_link).permit(:link))
```

You could move the new argument used in create to a strong params definition, like:

```
private

def watched_link_params
  params.require(:watched_link).permit(:link)
end
```

Then you can just update the create action to:

```
@links = WatchedLink.new(watched_link_params)
```

Also consider taking a look to the [`ActionController::StrongParameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

Comment: Same thing happens, only the time stamps are saved.

Comment: Update the `@link` variable in create to `@links = WatchedLink.new(params.require(:watched_link).permit(:watched_link))` same error?

Comment: I have changed the param in the view from `<%= f.text_field (:link) %>` to `<%= f.text_field (:watched_link) %>` and added `@links = WatchedLink.new(params.require(:watched_link).permit(:watched_link))` to the controller and now I get `NoMethodError in LinksToBeScraped#index
`

Comment: What's the full error you're getting. It seems your WatchedLink class doesn't have the attribute, if so, keep `link` in the form.

Comment: Thank very much the updated answer fix it but you need to edit the `.permit(:watched_link)` to `permit(:link)` in that function.